# Mayflash Gamecube adapter LR triggers always on

Tags: pc, controllers, emulation, nintendo-gamecube

Using the latest drivers/firmware from Mayflash's website doesn't seem to change anything. This happens with every GC controller I plug in.

[This guide](http://www.raphnet.net/electronique/gc_n64_usb_manual/index_en.php) sheds some light on exactly the problem I'm having, however the fix only works with the adapter on that site.

Below are the default settings:

[image: Mayflash Settings]

I've tried modifying the calibration, which *does* set the analog Rx/Ry values back to 0, however it also throws both joysticks completely out of whack. It's either one or the other.

Unfortunately every game is unplayable right now due to the triggers setting any and every button assignment to R-/R+!

Comment: Is it a new adapter? Given that you already tried using more GC controllers I'd say the adapter is busted.

Comment: @Zenjack Yes it's a new adapter. Would you recommend the official Nintendo adapter as a replacement?

Comment: @Chris Bornhoft the adapter isn't broken. The software just lacks calibration options. Delete the drivers, calibrate with the windows' own software and re-install the drivers if you need the rumble.

Comment: @ChrisBornhoft You mean the Wii U adapter? Hmm afaik, that adapter is specifically designed to work with the Wii U. There are third party drivers to make them work on PC's, but I wouldn't trust too much on them. I'd recommend returning the adapter if possible. Or asking for a refund. Thing is those adapters are supposed to work out of the box, you shouldn't have to make any adjustments, except for rumble.